# USB Ubuntu installation failure

Tags: usb-installation

I have created a Ubuntu installation on a USB stick using the notes and all completes without any reported problems.

When I insert the USB stick into the target laptop and reboot from USB the stick flashed for the screen show GRUB in the top left-hand corner but nothing else happens.

I've prepared two usb sticks with the same result.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

John

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138214/discussion-on-question-by-froschling-usb-ubuntu-installation-failure).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I would recommend using Rufus. Then make a USB into a bootable disk by doing these steps:

First, go to https://rufus.ie/en/ and download the latest version.

Plug in a USB into a port on your computer (Remember, the USB is going to be formatted, so back it up).

Run the Rufus EXE that you downloaded.

If you have several USBs plugged in, select the one you want to turn into a bootable disk (be careful to select the right one). If you only have one USB plugged in, it will select it for you.

Select your Ubuntu ISO file.

Next, click start.

Wait until it finishes and take out (eject) your new bootable disk (USB) and plug it into the computer (your Ubuntu target).

Boot from the USB.

It should boot into the Ubuntu install menu.

Install it.